# script to auto-generate ajax url's for google analytics?

Tags: ajax, google-analytics

I inherited a site that's completely built using Ajax so I'm using this code to detect pageloads:

```
(the standard GA code)
    var _gaq=[["_setAccount","UA-#######-#"],["_trackPageview"]];
    (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=1;
    g.src=("https:"==location.protocol?"//ssl":"//www")+".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,"script"));

and the gaq.push:
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/#pagename']);
```

except this is a big site with over 30 pages and I dont want to have to write in every one. is there a script that can find the paths/pagenames and put it in there for me?

I don't know Ajax OR Javascript, so apologies if this is not worded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `_push` function however because an AJAX request can mean so many things (sometimes a page load, sometimes a postback of data, and sometimes just a ping to make sure the user is still alive) you wouldn't want to track every XMLHttp request.

Depending on what language your site is written in, I would strongly suggest making use of some form of partial page component (php include, ASP.NET MVC Partial, ServerSide Include) etc which would stop you re-writing the code a million times if you change it.

However you will still need to edit your 30'odd pages if they are hard-coded. Or one master page if its a sensible design.

Check out [this link](http://davidwalsh.name/ajax-analytics) for a sample on how to track ajax requests using the push method.